# How to write a loop that find the frequency of value and stop by enter number -100

Tags: python, loops, numbers, frequency

```
numbers = input("Enter the numbers: ")
count = {}
for i in numbers:
    if i == '-100':
        break
        print('Done')
    elif i in count:
        count[i] +=1
    else:
        count[i] = 1
        
for key,value in count.items():
    print(f'{key}:{value}')
```

I just don't understand how to use the 'break' to stop the loop. Can anyone helps me to fix that? thanks

Comment: What you have will do that, but remember that the `break` exits the loop IMMEDIATELY, so the `print` won't run.  You'd need that before the break.  The bigger problem is that `numbers` is just going to be one big string.  How are they going to enter the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `while` loop for your case like this

```
count = {}
while True:
    numbers = input("Enter the numbers: ")
    if numbers == '-100':
        print('Done')
        break
    
    count[numbers] = count.setdefault(numbers, 0) + 1

for key,value in count.items():
    print(f'{key}:{value}')
```